# Indentation (and wrap-indentation) of debug strings output by printf()/fprintf() in C program

Tags: c, string, printf

I'm using a debug output using `printf()` in my functions, but the output goes to the console starting at the 1st columns. I'd like to distinguish the nesting level of functions by indenting their output strings each time I dive into the function (it's implemented easily having a `static int indentlevel;` variable, which is incremented at the beginning of a function, used as a space-filler-count and decremented at the end). But the flaw is that once the output line becomes too long to be wrapped at the console edge, lines' wrapped parts start at column 1 of the console. Should I take care about this, since once the output is redirected to a file, lines are, say, one-line-length, and widths of the lines depend only on the text file viewer settings?

Comment: But the width of the line isn't also configurable by the console's settings?

Comment: By resizing the console window? It's still limited to maximum screen width.

Comment: No.It is usually in the buffer width.If you increase that the lines are longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are writing to a text file, you shouldn't take care of line wrapping and let the text viewer decide.

An approach that I've used is to write to HTML - then the browser takes care of line wrapping. The only gotcha is that you need to watch out that the open/end tags are properly balanced, but you would also need that for your `indentlevel` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc you can use the -finstrument-functions compiler option to cause an instrumentation function to be called at the entry and exit of each function.

```
      void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
                                     void *call_site);
      void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
                                     void *call_site);
```

You can define these functions to keep track of the nesting level.

WARNING: I haven't actually tried this (yet another of those things I haven't quite got around to!). One obvious GOTHCA - don't instrument the instrumentation functions!!!

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html